# Find by conditions with * wildcards

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, find

I have a search form with two params. If a param is empty I'd like to search all.

```
var_1 = params[:var_1].blank? ? "*" : params[:var_1]
var_2 = params[:var_2].blank? ? "*" : params[:var_2]

@mymodels = MyModel.find(:all,:conditions=>["var_1 = ? and var_2 = ?",var_1,var_2])
```

This is what I got:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (var_1 = '*' and ...
```

what I need is:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (var_1 = * and ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would build up the list of criteria conditionally. i.e. only include a field in the query if the corresponding parameter is not blank:

```
conditions = []
values = []
[:var1, :var2].each do |field|
  unless params[field].blank?
    conditions << "#{field} = ?"
    values << params[:field]
  end
end
```

and then run the `find`:

```
MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => [conditions.join(" AND "), values])
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess having `SELECT ... WHERE (var_1 = * and ...` will not work anyway, as what you need there is a like clause,

Ex: `SELECT ... WHERE var_1 like '%' and ...`

So one option should be, have a separate method:

Ex:

```
def mymodel_list(var1, var2)
  @mymodels = nil
  if var1 && var2
    @mymodels = MyModel.find(:all,:conditions=>["var_1 = ? and var_2 = ?",var_1,var_2])
  else
    @mymodels = MyModel.find(:all) 
  end  
  @mymodels
end
```

IMO, sometimes it better to write more code, so that the logic can manage easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into building up a modifiable query, as arel is built upon this idea.

For example,

```
query = Model.scoped
query = query.where(:var1 => params[:var1]) if params[:var1].present?
query = query.where(:var2 => params[:var2]) if params[:var2].present?
... more conditions
@models = query.all # returns the array, finally
```

I used Model::scoped here to be able to continue my searches, because it
returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object, and not an array like Model.all
would.

I've found it helpful to start broad searches and then narrow them down.

Hope it helps,

-Luke